# HighCharts : Xaxis lables misplaced

Tags: json, highcharts

I want to label  xaxis with values from JSON data that is happening but it is printing it at wrong place as shown in screenshot :

[image]

Here only seven values are present its labeled in that manner but actual data is plotted by leaving a gap of one. For example at 11th there is value and then again at 13t so total seven values but taking 14 places and label properly taking there first seven places how to match labels and bar graph

Following is my code snippet :

```
var obj = data[$("#host").val()].stats_vol.result.sectoutput;
      var my_data_list = [];
      var my_data_list1 = [];
      var my_data_list2 = [];
      var volumes = [];
      for(var key in obj) {
          var avg_latency = parseInt(obj[key].avg_latency);
          var read_latency = parseInt(obj[key].read_latency);
          var write_latency = parseInt(obj[key].write_latency);
                console.log(key);
                volumes.push(key);
                my_data_list.push('Average Latency', parseInt(avg_latency));
                my_data_list1.push('Read Latency', parseInt(read_latency));
                my_data_list2.push('Write Latency', parseInt(write_latency));

          } 

  $('#graphcontainer3').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Volume Level Latency'
    },


    yAxis: {

        tickInterval: 100,


        title: {
            text: 'Latency(ms)'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: volumes,

    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} ms</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 2
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Average latency',
        data: my_data_list,

    }, {
        name: 'Read Latency',
        data: my_data_list1,

    }, {
        name: 'Write Latency ',
        data: my_data_list2,


    }]
});
```

Can anyone help me in this code to make this work fine???

Comment: How your data in series does it look like? Please note that categories are indexed from 0, so in your data array points, you need to refer to proper index of category.

Comment: @SebastianBochan   I understood that its my_data_list which is creating problem when I tried giving static value in data its plotting properly.But avg_latency which I am pushing using my_data_list array also contains 8 values then why its behaving like that in plot.

Comment: i=my_data_list.push('Average Latency', avg_latency);
console.log(i);   I tried to console.log the my_data_list its printing : 2 4 6 8 10 12 likewise.How to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I rectified the problem by myself :)  It just I was giving labels two times

```
  var obj = data[$("#host").val()].stats_vol.result.sectoutput;
      var my_data_list3 = [];
      var my_data_list1 = [];
      var my_data_list2 = [];
      var volumes = [];
      for(var key in obj) {
          var avg_latency = parseInt(obj[key].avg_latency);
          var read_latency = parseInt(obj[key].read_latency);
          var write_latency = parseInt(obj[key].write_latency);
                console.log(avg_latency);
                volumes.push(key);
                my_data_list3.push(parseInt(avg_latency));   //here no need to give label again as it is done my volume(key)
                my_data_list1.push( parseInt(read_latency));
                my_data_list2.push(parseInt(write_latency)); 
                                  
          }
```

[image]

This is what I was expecting as output .Hope it might be helpful for someone else hence answered.